# How to transfer funds online from a Canadian CIBC account to RBC instantly?

Tags: canada, bank-account, online-banking, wire-transfer, electronic-payment

I thought Interac transfer is instant but my mom wants to send me money from her CIBC account but she said it takes 2-3 business days?  What method can be used to transfer from a CIBC checking to a RBC checking instantly? It's urgent.

Comment: interac transfer is as fast as email.

Comment: Interac e-Transfer should take at most a few hours but it has a limit of $1000 to $3000 per day depending on the bank. If you are sending more, you may use Wire Transfer in branch.